# multiple responsive owl carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive, custom-data-attribute, owl-carousel-2

i need to create multiple responsive owl carousel in some page, i need to works with Data Attributes. I work like this but i cant do responsive my carousel,

**jQuery**

```
var $carousel = $('.data-carousel[data-carousel]');
if ($carousel.length) {
    $carousel.each(function() {
        $(this).owlCarousel($(this).data('carousel'));
    });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="owl-carousel data-carousel" data-carousel='{"margin": 10, "items": 4, "center": "true", "loop": true}'>

    <div class="item"><h1>1</h1></div>
    <div class="item"><h1>2</h1></div>
    <div class="item"><h1>3</h1></div>
    <div class="item"><h1>4</h1></div>

</div>
```

now i need to responsive my owl carousel , and i do like this ...

**HTML**

```
<div class="owl-carousel data-carousel" data-carousel='{"margin": 10, "items": 4, "center": "true", "loop": true, "responsive": "{0:{items:1},768:{items:2},992:{items:3}"}'>

    <div class="item"><h1>1</h1></div>
    <div class="item"><h1>2</h1></div>
    <div class="item"><h1>3</h1></div>
    <div class="item"><h1>4</h1></div>

</div>
```

but responsive option, dose't works. i see in owl carousel documentation and there is this :

**jQuery**

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    responsiveClass:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1,
            nav:true
        },
        600:{
            items:3,
            nav:false
        },
        1000:{
            items:5,
            nav:true,
            loop:false
        }
    }
});
```

i need to create some dynamic and responsive carousel in my page and i should be use Data Attributes ...

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the `responsive` argument as a string in your markup, and you have a missing closing bracket in the end:

```
"responsive": "{0:{items:1},768:{items:2},992:{items:3}"
//             ^ This bracket is not closed!
```

Remove the quotes so that it is parsed as an object instead of a literal string:

```
"responsive": {0:{"items":1},768:{"items":2},992:{"items":3}}
```

In other words, your markup should look like this:

```
<div class="owl-carousel data-carousel" data-carousel='{"margin": 10, "items": 4, "center": "true", "loop": true, "responsive": {0:{"items":1},768:{"items":2},992:{"items":3}}}'>

    <div class="item"><h1>1</h1></div>
    <div class="item"><h1>2</h1></div>
    <div class="item"><h1>3</h1></div>
    <div class="item"><h1>4</h1></div>

</div>
```

Comment: i do it but options dose't works, when i use <div class="owl-carousel data-carousel" data-carousel='{ "responsive": "{0:{items:1},768:{items:2},992:{items:3}"}'> other options works and responsive dosent work , but when i do like your way "responsive": {0:{"items":1},768:{"items":2},992:{"items":3} , all of options dosnet works

Comment: @ShahePars Updated my answer. Seems like you forgot a `}` at the end.

Comment: with your new answer all of options dose't work, its mean , responsive dosent work, margin dos't work and ... no options dosent works. i try many ways but i dont know how to responsive my carousel with data Attributes... @Terry

Answer (score 0):

If you are using v1.3.3 please try the following...

```
$(".myClass").owlCarousel({
    autoPlay: false,
    navigation: true,
    items: 4,
    itemsCustom: [
        [0, 1],
        [320, 1],
        [480, 2],
        [600, 2],
        [768, 2],
        [992, 3],
        [1200, 4]
    ]
});
```

This is how I manage responsive sizing within my solution.

Answer (score 0):

update in OCT 2020

responsive: JSON data mention how many items show in particular resolution
{0:{item:1}}  it shows only 1 item slider below the screen resolution

based on the screen resolution show the not id slider item.

```
$('.brand-img').owlCarousel({
    loop: false,
    margin: 10,
    nav: true,
    dots: true,
    mouseDrag: true,
    autoplay:true,
    items:1,
    responsive: {
        0: {
            items: 1,
            nav: true,
            mouseDrag: true,
            autoplay: true,
            dots: true,
        },

        576: {
            items: 3,
            nav:true,
            dots: true,
            mouseDrag: true,
            autoplay: true,
        },
        
        767: {
            items: 3,
            nav: true,
            mouseDrag: true,
            autoplay: true,
        },
        992: {
            items: 4,
            nav: true,
            loop: false,
            margin: 20,
        },
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove `"items": 4,` as you already mentioned items in `responsive:`

```
<div class="owl-carousel data-carousel" data-carousel='{"margin": 10, "center": "true", "loop": true, "responsive": "{0:{items:1},768:{items:2},992:{items:3}"}'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add below HTML structure and can change the value of data attributes as per your requirement. You can also add other data-* attribute to access other functionalities of owl carousel by adding them to Js file in the same manner.

```
<div class="owl-carousel" data-mobileview="1" data-tabletview="2" data-laptopview="3" data-mainview="3" data-autopaly="true" data-spacebetween="30" data-speed="8000" data-navigation="false" data-navdots="false">
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Js File

```
    $('.owl-carousel').each(function() {
        var mobile_view = $(this).data('mobileview');
        var tablet_view = $(this).data('tabletview');
        var laptop_view = $(this).data('laptopview');
        var main_view = $(this).data('mainview');
        var auto_play = $(this).data('autopaly');
        var space_between = $(this).data('spacebetween');
        var speed = $(this).data('speed');
        var navigation = $(this).data('navigation');
        var navdots = $(this).data('navdots');
        $(this).owlCarousel({
            loop: true,
            autoplay: auto_play,
            autoplayTimeout: speed,
            margin: space_between,
            nav: navigation,
            dots: navdots,
            responsive: {
                0: {
                    items: mobile_view
                },
                768: {
                    items: tablet_view
                },
                1190: {
                    items: laptop_view
                },
                1380: {
                    items: main_view
                }
            }
        });
```