# How do i make Owl Carousel width work responsively

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel

My issue. I have various `owl carousels` with a bootstrap div. I would like the owl to be the **100% width** of that div. However Owl will not go along with this, it only seems to work with a fixed width.

Is it possible to get owl to be 100 of the parent div? For example:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="owl-carousel" id="owl-example">
                <!-- owl content goes in here (its dynamically loaded) -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="owl-carousel-3" id="owl-example-2">
                <!-- owl content goes in here (its dynamically loaded) -->
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

I need the owl to take a look at the parent, for example "`col-md-8`" and see it's at 50% or whatever width bootstrap has set it as pixels.

Any one help with this, driving me crazy, is jquery the answer?

Comment: did you check the documation ? did you made some google research ? am sure it's a common issue ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multiple responsive owl carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46401108/multiple-responsive-owl-carousel)

Comment: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/responsive.html

Comment: https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/issues/1242

Comment: hi yes of course i did. The number of items to show for different screen sizes is not the issue, that works fine with the responsive breakpoints. This is nothing to do with the size of the owl-carousel div, that is the issue.

Comment: If you dont set a static width for the owl-carousel it ignores the parent width (as above in the example) and makes the page too wide.

I need to know how to get owl-carousel to be 100% width and take the width of its parent.

Comment: can anyone help?